# Can't use angular2-materialize (TypeError: jQuery.easing is undefined)

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, angular2-materialize

Hello everyone and thanks for reading.
Well, this is the error I get when running *ng serve*:

```
TypeError: jQuery.easing is undefined
```

And this is exactly what I did:

```
ng new X
cd X
npm install materialize-css --save
npm install angular2-materialize --save
npm install jquery@^2.2.4 --save
```

Then added this to **angular-cli.json** scripts block

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
],
```

This lines to **app.module.ts**

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';
import "materialize-css";
```

And this is the **NgModule** imports block

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterializeModule
],
```

Added Google icons to **index.html**

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

And this to global styles.css

```
@import "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";
```

I don't know what's wrong with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

After the imports try adding:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
```

I'm using jQuery in a few apps I am working on, and I have to declare $ to be able to use jQuery functions.

```
declare var $: any;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time :)